# Working from home PC but web development on different server

Tags: linux, windows, project, development-environment

I always do web development on my localhost PC with WAMP installed.

Now I want to do web development (PHP) on a dedicated server. But, I will be working on my PC. I don't want to keep updating/uploading the files via FTP or use a Text Editor that support FTP save.

I want something that feel like I'm working from localhost, but, the files are stored on dedicated server. So I can browse the files, view thumbnail images, edit php files from any text editors just like what you do in Windows Explorer.

Is there a solution to do that?

Comment: It depends on your server. You probably can log in in ssh and thus use WinSCP. But most of us simply code locally and use a script to deploy on the server using scp (or ftp if it's a crappy server).

Comment: Using WinSCP does not feel like using Windows Explorer..  Also it will not allow you to use any text editors if you use WinSCP  I think. Also I want to view images thumbs

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back With WinSCP, you can use whatever editor you'd like. See options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP is your best option. You can use the [explorer view](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_explorer) to emulate a windows explorer style interface and edit files using your editor of choice (see the preferences).

Viewing of thumbnail images is a feature that is on the radar of the devs, but not currently possible. Here is the [bugtracker link](https://winscp.net/tracker/912).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply mount remote filesystem using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) or [samba](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/165).